# EthereumJ IO Error Too many open files

Tags: ethereumj, bug

While using EthereumJ: `SocketException` or `leveldb.DBException` are thrown:

> leveldb.DBException: IO error: /data/bitgo/database/state/549361.ldb: Too many open files

Comment: here is an opened issue it seems to be a bug : https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/issues/453

Comment: A link to an open bug is [considered a valid answer](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/117/87).

Comment: could this be a O.S system limitation, are you linux/unix? check whats your ulimit -a for files? do you have more than 1024 (usual limit for open files on linux) files open ?